# Как передать декоратору параметры из конфига

Tags: python, декоратор

Такая задача. Программа считывает параметры работы из терминала, при помощи argparse. Попадают они туда через json файлы конфигов, притом не в том виде, в котором их привык видеть argparse, но не суть, я их привожу к нужному ему виду и паршу уже список строк в нужном ему виде, условно

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser  
args = transform_input_args(sys.argv[1:])  
final_args = parser.parse_argument(args)
```

Но вопрос не в этом. У меня есть самописный декоратор с параметрами. Мне бы очень хотелось, чтобы эти параметры задавались в файле конфига. Основная логика скрипта находится в блоке `if __name__ == '__main__'`, на некоторые вызываемые из него функции этот декоратор и повешен. Получается, считывание аргументов идет в нем, но как я понял у декоратора параметры  должны быть установлены ДО Run time и потому у меня не выходит установить у него считанные из конфига параметры.
Кто нибудь в курсе как можно провернуть мою задумку?

Comment: приведите мало-мальский пример того что вы хотите сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужны параметры на момент вызова декорированной функции (а не в момент привязки декоратора), то можно создать объект с методом-декоратором. Сначала объект создается, его метод навешивается на функции. Потом в блоке `if __name__ == "__main__":` вы устанавливаете нужные параметры в объект, потом вызываете функции.

Пример:

```
import functools


class RunLogger:
    file_name: str = None
    
    def decorator(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.file_name is not None:
                with open(self.file_name, "a") as file:
                    print(f"Функция {func.__name__} вызвана с параметрами args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}", file=file)
            else:
                print("Имя файля для декоратора не установлено")
            
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


logger = RunLogger()


@logger.decorator
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.file_name = "calls.txt"
    print(plus(2, b=3))
```

Выведет 5, в файл calls.txt запишется `Функция plus вызвана с параметрами args=(2,), kwargs={'b': 3}`.

Также можно сам декоратор реализовать не как функцию, а как класс с методом `__call__`, в объект этого класса аналогично перед вызовом декорируемой функции можно прописать нужные параметры. Все аналогично, только имя метода `decorator` в примере выше меняется на `__call__`, и функция декорируется самим объектом, а не его методом:

```
import functools


class RunLogger:
    file_name: str = None
    
    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if self.file_name is not None:
                with open(self.file_name, "a") as file:
                    print(f"Функция {func.__name__} вызвана с параметрами args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}", file=file)
            else:
                print("Имя файля для декоратора не установлено")
            
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


logger = RunLogger()


@logger
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.file_name = "calls.txt"
    print(plus(2, b=3))
```

---

Еще вариант - использовать обычный параметризованный декоратор, при инициализации передавать в него какой-то объект контейнер параметров, потом до вызова функции записывать в контейнер конкретные значения:

```
import functools


class Config:
    file_name: str = None


def parametrized_decorator(config: Config):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if config.file_name is not None:
                with open(config.file_name, "a") as file:
                    print(f"Функция {func.__name__} вызвана с параметрами args={args}, kwargs={kwargs}", file=file)
            else:
                print("Имя файля для декоратора не установлено")
            
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


config = Config()


@parametrized_decorator(config)
def plus(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config.file_name = "calls.txt"
    print(plus(2, b=3))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало